# Disk Management problem (in Windows) creating space to install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, helpfile

I tried to do a second partition on my PC and now on the disk management is saying that is in simple volume.

I want to change it back to normal (with the blue color). I was trying to do the second partition because I want to install Ubuntu on it. now i don't know how to get the disk management back to normal, and the color of my C:, E:, and E: are yellow.

[image]

I read on a forum that if my disk is dynamic I cannot boot into Windows 7 again after installing Ubuntu. I am scared things may already be broken in this way--what do i do now?

Comment: OMG @user82016 don't you see the site name? It's ask ubuntu not ask windows. You can not post question not related ubuntu.

Comment: @shantanu: but if the OP does it to install Ubuntu, doesn't it make the question valid for this site?

Comment: As Sergey has suggested, I think this is **on-topic**, since the OP is trying to use `diskmgmt.msc` in Windows to *create space for an Ubuntu installation*. You can tell because (1) the question [stated it explicitly](http://askubuntu.com/posts/173263/revisions) (the reference to Ubuntu in the body is not something that I added), and (2) one of the volume names (of the partitions listed in the Disk Management screenshot) is Ubuntu. I've edited the post to clarify this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the question. There is a "free" Windows 7 partitioning tool for dual boot systems called "minitool partition wizard".

http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

It will provide the feature to convert a dynamic disk back to a basic disk;

http://www.partitionwizard.com/convertpartition/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.html

My 2c's:

You do not need to pre-create partitions for the Ubuntu install and in my humble opinion it is safer not to.

I say this as the Ubuntu partition manager will find and allocate the free disk space for you during the install process.

This avoids accidentally selecting the wrong partition (i.e. the windows c: drive ;-).

I would also check if 14GB will be enough space long term?

Lastly, (more an FYI) remember to boot from the Live CD / USB and test that all your required hardware is working prior to running the Ubuntu install process.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: i was reading in some forums and it said that if i use that software it could damage my disk, remember my OS is in the c: drive and the c: drive is on dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is having the same issue, don't worry, the dynamic disk won't affect you PC, mine is working fine and i haven't got a problem.  leave it on dynamic, don't change it back, because you can delete you data.